# How to write large Spark DataFrame(1.2 GB 14M rows) to an MSSQL Server tbl? My current solution takes around 10 hours

Tags: sql-server, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, azure-databricks, sql-server-2019

**Problem:**
*1.2 GB (14 Millions  records) stored in an apache spark dataframe. The computation took less than 1 min but the writing to an MSSQL SERVER table (non-indexed) takes more than 10 hours.* **Hardware:** (1-VM 8-vcpus, 64 GB memory, SSD). Question:The following have been tried without success, would you have a brilliant ideas, suggestion or even a simple one to help? Thanks

```
def FUNC_A1(df):  
    start = time.time()
    jdbc_url = f"jdbc:sqlserver://{config.get('mydb',
    'host')}:1434;database={config.get('mydb', 'database')}"
    df.select("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5", "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9")\ 
      .write.format("jdbc").mode("overwrite") \
      .option("driver", "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver")\
      .option("url", jdbc_url) \
      .option("dbtable", "dbo.tblAFS") \
      .option("user", config.get('mydb', 'username'))\
      .option("password", config.get('mydb', 'password'))\
      .save()
```

The preceeding code creates the table, but when trying to insert the records it fails and  has generated the following error message;

[image: generated the following error message]

**Option #1** *(this code take 9 to 10 hours to complete, it’s writing the actual results(dataframe) into the table.*

---

```
     # Execute insert into tblAFS for each row in dataframe
     # Using fast execute

     start = time.time()
     df = df.select("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5",
          "F6", "F7", "F8", "F9").na.fill(0)
     conn = pyodbc.connect(shared.get_odbcconn(config))
     cursor = conn.cursor()
     cursor.fast_executemany = True
     collected = df.rdd.toLocalIterator()
     counter = 1
     for row in collected:
        cursor.execute("""
               INSERT INTO dbo.tblAFS 
               ([F1],[F2],[F3],[F4],[F5],[F6],[F7],[F8],[F9])
               VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)""",
                 row["F1"], row["F2"], row["F3"], row["F4"], row["F5"],
                 row["F6"], row["F7"], row["F8"], row["F9"])
        counter = counter + 1
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

**Option #2** _ takes as much time as Option #1_

```
def FUNC_C1(df):
    # 1. Create csv file for each F2 partition
    # 2. Bulk insert all files generated in table tblAFS

    start = time.time()
    file_path = config.get('action', 'stats_results')
    df = df.select("F1", "F2", "F3", "F4", "F5",
                   "F6", "F7", "F8", "F70").na.fill(0)

    df.write.mode("overwrite").options(header=True).csv(file_path)
    conn = pyodbc.connect(shared.get_odbcconn(config))
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.fast_executemany = True
    files = glob(f"{file_path}/*.csv")
    counter = 1
    for file in files:
        cursor.execute(f"BULK INSERT dbo.tblAFS FROM '{getcwd()}/{file}' 
             WITH (FORMAT = 'CSV', FIRSTROW = 2)")
        counter = counter+1
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

## The following ideas have been considered but have not been implemented with a significant time reduction in processing time.

---

- rdd.collect() should not be used in this case as it will collect all
  data as an Array in the driver, which is the easiest way to get out
  of memory.
- rdd.coalesce(1).saveAsTextFile() should also not be used as the
  parallelism of upstream stages will be lost to be performed on a
  single node, where data will be stored from.
- rdd.coalesce(1, shuffle = true).saveAsTextFile() is the best simple
  option as it will keep the processing of upstream tasks parallel and
  then only perform the shuffle to one node
  (rdd.repartition(1).saveAsTextFile() is an exact synonym).
- rdd.saveAsSingleTextFile() as provided bellow additionally allows one
  to store the rdd in a single file with a specific name while keeping
  the parallelism properties of rdd.coalesce(1, shuffle =
  true).saveAsTextFile().

Comment: Your stated numbers equate to approx. 389 rows inserted per second, and that is far too low.  if you're on a VM maybe your have noisy neighbours? Does the SQL Server have a memory reservation set at the host? It should.....

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways. First, delete indexes, primary keys and foreign keys, insert the date in that table using your spark job. After job is finished, recreate de indexes, primary keys and foreign keys.

Or, you can create a new table, lets say table-temp with the same structure as original table but without any constrains. Insert in the table-temp your data and update you original table using table temp.

Using the first way, a few days ago i inserted in a Oracle DB 500-800 millions rows in 40 minutes.

Comment: Don't drop PK's or FK's for obvious reasons (also, you might be confusing PK with clustering key)

Comment: This depend if the target table from DB is an empty table or if already contain data. If the target table contain already date, the correct approach is to use a temp-table.

Comment: Inserting data in a SQL database is not influenced by cluster key. Its influenced by number of connections made by Spark executors, the number of constraints used by that table and by the batch size.

Comment: "Inserting data in a SQL database is not influenced by cluster key" - that is incorrect.

Comment: Why "Inserting data in a SQL database is not influenced by cluster key" is incorrect?